# FTP Code Not Working on Client PC

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file, ftp

I have a particular VBA code which FTPs file to a location.

```
    Function SendFtpFile_F(csvPath As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim rc As Integer
    Dim iFreeFile As Integer
    Dim sFTPUserID As String
    Dim sFTPPassWord As String
    Dim sWorkingDirectory As String
    Dim sFileToSend As String

    Const FTP_BATCH_FILE_NAME = "myFtpFile.ftp"
    Const INCREASED_BUFFER_SIZE = 20480

     fsheetname = ActiveSheet.Name

       Select Case fsheetname

      Case "Price Change"

       flocation = "price_change"

     Case "New SKU"

    flocation = "new_sku"

    Case "SKU Change"

      flocation = "sku_change"

      Case "Discontinuation"

       flocation = "sku_deletion"

     End Select


    SendFtpFile_F = False

   'csvPath = "C:\Users\10613527\Desktop\test\"
   csvPath = csvPath + "\"
    sWorkingDirectory = csvPath

    sFileToSend = Namex

    On Error GoTo FtpNECAFile_EH

    'Kill FTP process file if it exists
    If Dir(sWorkingDirectory & FTP_BATCH_FILE_NAME) <> "" Then
        Kill sWorkingDirectory & FTP_BATCH_FILE_NAME
    End If

    'Create FTP process file
    iFreeFile = FreeFile
    Open sWorkingDirectory & FTP_BATCH_FILE_NAME For Output As #iFreeFile
    Print #iFreeFile, "open " & FTP_ADDRESS
    Print #iFreeFile, FTP_USERID
    Print #iFreeFile, FTP_PASSWORD
    Print #iFreeFile, "ASCII"
    Print #iFreeFile, "CD " & flocation
    Print #iFreeFile, "put """ & sWorkingDirectory & sFileToSend & """"
    Print #iFreeFile, "bye"
    Close #iFreeFile

    'Shell command the FTP file to the server
    Shell "ftp -i -w:20480 -s:" & sWorkingDirectory & FTP_BATCH_FILE_NAME

    SendFtpFile_F = True

    GoTo FtpNECAFile_EX

    FtpNECAFile_EH:
        MsgBox "Err", Err.Name

    FtpNECAFile_EX:

     Exit Function


    End Function
```

This code works Perfectly in my Machine but the FTP part does not work in my clienr's machine.

**Observation**: When I run this code without printing the "BYE" command then on my PC i can see a command line pop up showing the successful transfer but the same does not happen in my client PC. The cmd window does not even open, I have noticed that the FTP batch file is written perfectly no issues there. Please help.

Comment: try to set a complete path to the ftp.exe. Adding something like ` > c:\temp\error.log` might store any error messages printed by ftp.exe for later viewing.

Comment: @Marged Its writing the file , creating it , I am not sure if i am getting what you are meaning by "Set complete path" Thanks

Comment: @Anarach, the complete path to where the Windows FTP.exe file exists. I had this happen to me a few years ago where we had a 3rd party ftp program installed on our computers and when my code executed it found ftp.exe from the 3rd party program first because it was higher up in my PATH variable.

Comment: Can you ask your client to run a portable teamviewer so that you can debug the code? Otherwise I'd log what's happening in VBA code after *every* line in the code into a logfile so that the client could send it to me (be sure to mention there's no private information as they can see themselves prior to sending it).

Comment: "C:\windows\system32\ftp.exe -i -w:20480 -s:" & sWorkingDirectory & FTP_BATCH_FILE_NAME & " > C:\temp\ftp.log". Checking if the ftp.exe exists at the location you assume and printing a diagnostic message if it is missing is a good idea too.

Comment: Oh.. I will try that, thanks guys will update tomorrow

Comment: @Marged Not Working mate :-(

Comment: You should definitely tell us which approaches you tried and what exactly is not working. Is there a ftp.exe at the location you try to run it ? Did you try setting an absolute path?

Comment: I changed the "Shell "ftp -i -w:20480 -s:" & sWorkingDirectory & FTP_BATCH_FILE_NAME" to shell "C:\windows\system32\ftp.exe -i -w:20480 -s:" & sWorkingDirectory & FTP_BATCH_FILE_NAME Still , Let me be clear, ON my PC WORKS like a charm but on another PC in the Philippines where i need to deploy the code , i can see the command line open and close in like half a second, on my PC it will stay open since i am not giving the "bye" command.

Comment: @Marged And yes There is a FTP.exe in the path where i am trying to access

Comment: Did you try to call the command manually from a shell ? Perhaps ftp.exe is throwing an error you don´t see. But if an error occurs it should be written to the log you specify by using `>`, perhaps you need to add a `2> error2.log` to see messages from stderr

Comment: @Marged I wanted to ask this, How do you exactly append the log in my code, ? I tried so many times but shows all kind of errors , can you add it for me and put it here , I tried like this shell "C:\windows\system32\ftp.exe -i -w:20480 -s:" & sWorkingDirectory & FTP_BATCH_FILE_NAME & " > C:\temp\ftp.log" I get error "OBJECT DOESNT SUPPORT PROPERTY"

Comment: Perhaps now is the time to stop calling ftp.exe and trying to script it. Better try to get a library that does the ftp stuff for you. Perhaps this here will help, the post is in German but the code is English ;-) http://www.office-loesung.de/ftopic400253_0_0_asc.php

Comment: @Marged Also Something interesting i found out that i created a .VBS script file , which i created using macro, when i run it manually it works but when i run it though the macro it does the same thing, pops up the command line for 1micro second and close and does not run

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92711/discussion-between-anarach-and-marged).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The File is working now, It seems that the Batch file should be in the same location as the output file and there should be no other files in the output location.

For example you cannot save the file in desktop , the shell extension is not able to read it if there are lot of files in the destination directory.

FIX: On creating another folder in desktop and saving the file there and then executing the FTP is successful.

Answer (score -2):

If it were me, I think I'd toggle the PASV command in the ftp file itself to see if the client's firewall is blocking the DATA portion of this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer , not sure how to do that .. Could you help me

Comment: There's no `PASV` command in Windows FTP + The OP claims the FTP is not even started.

Comment: To whoever down-voted me it would be nice if you wouldn't do that for a working solution.  The command you want in the MS-DOS version of FTP would be: "quote pasv".  "quote" is how you send a command to the server to make a change and "pasv" will toggle the setting in question.